# How to get from which table a particular view is created in Snowflake through query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. I am building an application where I need to display the Table information(name and attributes) from which a particular View is created.

example:
[Snowflake views with its source tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYRlw.png)

So far I have tried the query from the following site but it did not give the source table of a particular view.

https://dataedo.com/kb/query/snowflake/list-views-with-their-scripts

So, is there a query where i can get the source Table of a particular View (with attributes involved).

Comment: You may need to parse view_definition(information_schema.views) to get the table name and use get_ddl to retrieve the table definition. Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html#syntax

Comment: Thanks @FKayani, I also thought that, but it will be a complex process, as a create view statement might be more complex :)

Comment: Have you tried the new Access History view?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view dependencies could be extracted using [GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html):

```
SELECT REFERENCED_DATABASE_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_OBJECT_TYPE,
       *
FROM TABLE(get_object_references(database_name=>'<db_name>',
                                 schema_name=>'<schema_name>',
                                 object_name=>'<view_name>'));
```

Column list could be queried using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html).

Comment: This is awesome thanks @LukaszSzozda, Is there also a way to get the attributes involved in creating a particular view from a table?
example: 
`create view v1 (pre_tax_profit, taxes, after_tax_profit) as
    select revenue - cost, (revenue - cost) * tax_rate, (revenue - cost) * (1.0 - tax_rate)
    from table1;`. In this example revenue, cost, tax_rate are involved in creating the view.

Comment: @KishorKumar That information could be  inferred from [ACCESS HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html). "SELECT * FROM view_name" and then checking access history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample query to pull column level metadata...

```
  select
        -- refr_tab.referenced_database_name,refr_tab.referenced_schema_name, refr_tab.referenced_schema_name,referenced_object_name
        ref_cols.*
    from
        table(
            get_object_references(
                database_name => 'ex1_gor_y',
                schema_name => 'public',
                object_name => 'y_view_f'
            )
        ) refr_tab,
        information_schema.columns ref_cols
    where
        refr_tab.referenced_object_type = 'TABLE'
        and refr_tab.referenced_schema_name = ref_cols.table_schema
        and refr_tab.referenced_object_name = ref_cols.table_name
        and ref_cols.table_name = 'Y_TAB_A';
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, When i run this query i think its pulling all the columns of the involved table even if one column is involved in creating the view.

Is there a way to get only the columns(table) involved while creating a view.